# Master Page and Update Panel problem

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a problem with master pages and asp net updatepanel.

```
MASTERPAGE
<div id="outerDiv">
    <asp:Button />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

PAGE
<asp:Content>
    <asp:UpdatePanel>
        blah blah
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

The outerDiv seems to blink every time I click the asp button (outside the updatepanel). In other words, on initial page load the outerDiv ignores the content in updatepanel/content, waits a couple of seconds and then expands to include the content in updatepanel.
This is giving the user the impression the page is flashing.

The weird thing is that the content in the updatepanel seems to have loaded before the div, only after the whole page has completed loading content does the outerDiv decide to increase it's height!?!?

I have searched for non closing divs spans etc but all is OK.

Does the UpdatePanel have issues with Masterpages?

Comment: I delete it because probably I do not understand the real issue, maybe some else can help better.

Comment: Will be using jQuery and postmethods.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the update panel property UpdateMode="Conditional"

Comment: Tried that. I suspect it has something to do with an updatepanel within an updatepanel. Thanks.

Comment: ... or even masterpage within a masterpage. This is something I did not mention before.